# Need help with test class for my first trigger, have researched!

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code

I am new to apex and SF and need help in writing a test class for my trigger.

This trigger runs every time a Calender event is created and updates the scheduled date and status on Opportunity. The trigger is working fine in Sandbox.

I created the given test class and it runs successfully but in dev-console, the test coverage displayed is 0%. This is my first time writing a test class and I have tried to research as much as I can before asking this question. 
Please be considerate and help, I am in urgent need. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
trigger UpdOpportunityStagefromEvent on Event (after insert , after update){

    Id optyId;

    for (Event evntObj: Trigger.new){
        optyId = evntObj.WhatId;
    }

    Event evntObj = [select Id, StartDateTime, LastModifiedDate from Event where WhatId =:optyId order by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1];

    date d = Date.newInstance(evntObj.StartDateTime.year(),evntObj.StartDateTime.month(),evntObj.StartDateTime.day());
    opportunity optyObj = [select Id from opportunity where Id = :optyId LIMIT 1];
    optyObj.StageName='Work Order Scheduled';
    optyObj.Scheduled_Work_Date__c = d;
    update optyObj;
}
```

---

Test Class:

---

@isTest
private class TestUpdOppfromEventTrigger {

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
Event e = new Event();
e.IsAllDayEvent = true;
e.ActivityDate = Date.today();

Opportunity optyObj = new Opportunity();
optyObj.StageName='Work Order Scheduled';
optyObj.Scheduled_Work_Date__c = Date.today();
optyObj.id = '006L0000005P1YW';
insert e;
update optyObj;

}
```

}

I made the changes given above and I am getting 66% coverage now. The last 3 lines in the trigger are not getting covered. Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: SFNoob, welcome to SFSE. I think you'l find that you get pretty rapid response on SFSE without having to use words like `urgent` which have a way of irritating the community. Just take a look at other posts where the response time to a well-formulated question can typically be in less than 1 hour.

Comment: Yes, it indeed looks like that. Will keep in mind in future. Thanks.

Comment: I would also comment that if you are just going to update the Opportunity, you don't need to query for it - you can just set the Id in the constructor, and update it directly

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is on Event, but your test inserts an Opportunity. You need to insert an Event and not an Opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Also - you have an Opportunity Id hard-coded in the test - but for the most part, when you run a test, it is isolated from the live data, so you need to create a new Opportunity in the test, insert that record, and then link the Event record to it.

The test still won't work as written - it should look more like this I think

```
@isTest private class TestUpdOppfromEventTrigger {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    Opportunity optyObj = new Opportunity();
    optyObj.Name = 'Test Record';
    optyObj.StageName='Work Order Scheduled';
    optyObj.Scheduled_Work_Date__c = Date.today();
    optyObj.CloseDate = system.today();

    insert optyObj;


  Event e = new Event();
  e.IsAllDayEvent = true;
  e.ActivityDate = Date.today();
  e.WhatId = optyObj.Id

  insert e;
//query for opportunity and check stage updated
}
}
```